# get the string used by localizedStandardCompare when it did a comparison

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, localization, nsstring

I'm sorting an array by using `localizedStandardCompare:`, which gives me the objects sorted in the correct, localized order. Now I want to use them in the `index` for a `UITableView`, which means I need to generate the section titles. Since `localizedStandardCompare:` localizes them, a string that starts with "Æ" is sorted with the A objects.

So if I iterate the array and make a section for each first letter, I'll get sections "A", "Æ", "A", "B", etc. Is there a way to get the string that was used for comparison, or at least emulate it? I've tried converting with different encodings, but none will return me an "A" for "Æ".

Any other suggestions for how to generate the section titles for localized strings?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this, but have you checked out `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`? Link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html

Comment: Thanks! I'd never noticed that class before and it looks like just what i need.

Comment: If this worked for you, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted so this question does not appear unanswered and other people with the same problem can find the solution more easily.

Comment: The actual question remains open - `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` is only an option if you can afford to load all data in memory.

Comment: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436143/string-comparison-for-localization

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CFStringTransform` method to get the used string.

For example use the `kCFStringTransformToLatin` value to get a simple latin string from the input string.

This won't actually behave exactly as the `localizedStandardCompare:` method, but you can use the string transform to generate an additional attribute for the object which you use for the actual sorting.

There are many good resources about this topic:

- [NSHipster about CFStringTransform](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/)
- [The Apple documentation about the function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001504-CH201-BCIGCACA)