# String comparison for localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring

What is the difference between `NSString`'s `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` and `localizedStandardCompare:` methods?

I read the reference but did not get a proper idea of which one to use.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293996/sorting-coredata-entity-with-a-nscomparisonresult

Its kind of similar..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` is equivalent to:

```
[aString compare:otherString
         options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
         range:NSMakeRange(0,aString.length)
        locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

`localizedStandardCompare:` is basically equivalent to:

```
[aString compare:otherString
         options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch
         range:NSMakeRange(0,aString.length)
        locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

So, the primary difference is in how numbers within strings are compared.

Comparing the following 3 strings using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` would result in the following order:

```
"Foo2.txt",
"Foo25.txt",
"Foo7.txt"
```

On the other hand, comparing them using `localizedStandardCompare:` would result in the following order:

```
"Foo2.txt",
"Foo7.txt",
"Foo25.txt"
```

While the `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` method has been around forever, the `localizedStandardCompare:` was only added recently (OS X 10.6). The Finder sorts filenames using the numeric method, and prior to the addition of `localizedStandardCompare:`, developers were without an easy way to assure they could sort strings like the Finder did.

When determining which one to use, if the strings you're comparing represent filenames, then you should definitely tend toward using `localizedStandardCompare:`.

Comment: Cool. So localizedStandardCompare can understand something in a string  more than caseInsensitiveCompare. Thanks for the examples.

Answer (score 0):

The latter sorts like Finder on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` is similar to `localizedCompare:`

They both return an `NSComparisonResult` value that indicates the lexical ordering of the receiver and another given string using a localized comparison.

The difference being that the former is `case insensitive`. i.e. it ignores the differing use of uppercase and lowercase letters when comparing the strings.

`localizedStandardCompare`
This compares strings as sorted by the Finder Application.